# passing reactive data object as argument in function Vue 3 composition API

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am new to Vue and although I could find way around most problems I've encountered, this one has been bugging me for last two days and just cannot find solution. Any help much appreciated, thanks in advance!

I've got following code:

```
<template>
  <header><h1>HomeShop</h1></header>

  <main>
    <section>
      <Item-Card
        v-for="(item, index) in items"
        :key="index"
        :item="item.item"
        :check="item.check"
        @item-checked="checkClicked(index, item.id, items)"
        @item-deleted="deleteClicked(item.id, items)"
      />

      <Add-New-Item @item-submited="newItemCard" />
    </section>
  </main>
    <button @click="$log(JSON.stringify(items, null, 1))">Log</button>
</template>

<script setup>
import { reactive, toRefs } from "vue";
import axios from "axios";
import _ from "lodash";

//data + explicit expression
const state = reactive({
  items: [],
});

const { items } = toRefs(state);

//fce
const checkClicked = (index, id, items) => {
  if (items[index].check === false) {
    items[index].check = true;
    items[index].checkTime = _.now();
    items = _.sortBy(items, ["check", "checkTime"])
    console.log(JSON.stringify(items, null, 1));
    axios.patch("http://localhost:3000/items/" + id, { check: true });
  } else {
    items[index].check = false;
    delete items[index].checkTime;
    axios.patch("http://localhost:3000/items/" + id, { check: false });
  }
};
```

I pass my data object array (*items*) as argument to checkClicked method. This function changes check status and adds checkTime timestamp based on which I sort the array (using lodash method sortBy). From within the checkClicked method I log the *items* array with expected correct result:

```
[
 {
  "item": "2",
  "check": false,
  "id": 2
 },
 {
  "item": "3",
  "check": false,
  "id": 3
 },
 {
  "item": "4",
  "check": false,
  "id": 4
 },
 {
  "item": "5",
  "check": true,
  "id": 5,
  "checkTime": 1671719753796
 },
 {
  "item": "1",
  "check": true,
  "id": 1,
  "checkTime": 1671719755363
 }
]
```

However, when I log items from outside the method (the custom function $log at template) I get following result:

```
[
 {
  "item": "1",
  "check": true,
  "id": 1,
  "checkTime": 1671719755363
 },
 {
  "item": "2",
  "check": false,
  "id": 2
 },
 {
  "item": "3",
  "check": false,
  "id": 3
 },
 {
  "item": "4",
  "check": false,
  "id": 4
 },
 {
  "item": "5",
  "check": true,
  "id": 5,
  "checkTime": 1671719753796
 }
]
```

How do I manipulate the reactive data object array *items* from inside the function checkClicked? My intention is to sort the data array each time timestamp checkTime is added (that is what the checkClicked function does).

My understanding is that passing the data object array *items* as argument into function creates separate instance of the array, that is why I am getting two different results while loging the array. However I cannot find solution how to manipulate the real *items* from inside the function checkClicked.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. You are only changing the parameter variable `items` in the function. See my other answer for the clarification.

**Pay also attention to the following:**

When you assign a new value to your reactive proxy object, you can lose the reactivity.

Here it is:

```
items = _.sortBy(items, ["check", "checkTime"])
```

I guess, this line could also remove reactivity from the array.

There are ways to fix it, by passing the array through vue reactivity system again.
But, this causes too much work for vue to full recalculate the array items and is not efficient.

**My way to provide sorted results is to use a [Computed Property](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html).**

Like this:

```
<Item-Card v-for="(item, index) in sortedItems">
```

and then

```
const sortedItems = computed(() => {
  return _.sortBy(items, ["check", "checkTime"])
})
```

The advantage of using a computed property is that, it will be recalculated by Vue Reactivity System only when your items array changes.

Comment: thanks for the answer, though it helped me progress somehow, it came with more problems. In the end, the solution is way simpler, see my other reply below. cheers

Comment: What kind of problems?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you only change the local variable `items` in the checkClicked() function. I have build a test playground to check it.

You have to change the line `items = [];` to `this.items = [];` if you want to change the property, not the parameter variable.

See my second answer for the right sorting solution.

```js
 const { ref, reactive, createApp, toRefs } = Vue;
  
 const data = [
 {
  "item": "1",
  "check": true,
  "id": 1,
  "checkTime": 1671719755363
 },
 {
  "item": "2",
  "check": false,
  "id": 2
 },
 {
  "item": "3",
  "check": false,
  "id": 3
 }
]
  
 const App = { 
    methods: {
        clear(items) {
          items = [];
        }
    },
    setup() {
    
    //data + explicit expression
    const state = reactive({
      items: data,
    });  

    const { items } = toRefs(state);

    return {
      items
    }
  }
}

 const app = createApp(App)
 app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app">
     <div v-for="(item, index) in items"
        :key="index"
        :item="item.item"
        :check="item.check"> #{{index}}: {{item.item}}
     </div>
     <button @click="clear(items)">clear</button>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"> 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

sending update with solution I got at another forum. I feel dumbed I would not figured that out in two days on my own, whatever. Although advice from Tolbxela can be right track it brings as well more problems so in the end I prefer the more cleaner way:

"I can reference the state declared within . i.e. don’t pass it as a value to the function."

Thats it. Simply not passing the data object array into function, just reference it right away from within the function. So the correct code goes like this:

```
<template>
  <header><h1>HomeShop</h1></header>

  <main>
    <section>
      <Item-Card
        v-for="(item, index) in items"
        :key="item.id"
        :item="item.item"
        :check="item.check"
        @item-checked="checkClicked(index, item.id)"
        @item-deleted="deleteClicked(item.id, items)"
      />

      <Add-New-Item @item-submited="newItemCard" />
    </section>
  </main>
  <button @click="$log(JSON.stringify(sortedItems, null, 1))">Log</button>
</template>

<script setup>
import { reactive, toRefs, computed } from "vue";
import axios from "axios";
import _ from "lodash";


//data + explicit expression
const state = reactive({
  items: [],
});

const { items } = toRefs(state);

//fce
const checkClicked = (index, id) => {
  if (state.items[index].check === false) {
    state.items[index].check = true;
    state.items[index].checkTime = _.now();
    state.items = _.sortBy(state.items, ["check", "checkTime"])
```